# Replace <input> with <select> to get video metadata info

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, metadata

I have this code I got it from web long time ago, It show video metadata (cover, title, etc.) It work fine when I pick video from local disk, now I need to change it to get info from select tag instead of input so I can use it in my website.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">
    <input type="file" id="input" name="file[]" class="file_multi_video" accept="video/*">
    <div id="cover"></div>
    <p id="title"></p>
    <p id="artist"></p>
    <p id="album"></p>
    <p id="genre"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
    <video controls>
  <source src="" id="video_here" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsmediatags/3.9.5/jsmediatags.min.js"></script>
 
      <script>
const jsmediatags = window.jsmediatags;

document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  
  const file = event.target.files[0];

  jsmediatags.read(file, {
    onSuccess: function(tag) { 

      // Array buffer to base64
      const data = tag.tags.picture.data;
      const format = tag.tags.picture.format;
      let base64String = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        base64String += String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
      }

      // Output media tags
      document.querySelector("#cover").style.backgroundImage = `url(data:${format};base64,${window.btoa(base64String)})`;
      
      document.querySelector("#title").textContent = tag.tags.title;
      document.querySelector("#artist").textContent = tag.tags.artist;
      document.querySelector("#album").textContent = tag.tags.album;
      document.querySelector("#genre").textContent = tag.tags.genre;
      },
      onError: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
  });  
});

    </script>

 <script>
$(document).on("change", ".file_multi_video", function(evt) {
  var $source = $('#video_here');
  $source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
  $source.parent()[0].load();
});
</script>
```

I changed the input:
`<input type="file" id="input" name="file[]" class="file_multi_video" accept="video/*">`
With:

```
<select id="input" name="file[]" class="file_multi_video" dir="rtl">
    <option value="#">Movies list</option>
    <option value="media/video/1stvideo.mp4">first</option>
    <option value="media/video/2ndvideo.mp4">second</option>
    <option value="media/video/3rdvideo.mp4">third</option>
</select>
```

But I got "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"
Thank you in advance

I tried to change it in many ways but it didn't work, Hope someone can tell me how to detect change in select tag that work with this code.

Comment: If you want to get information about a remote file you need to use AJAX and write a server script to get the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can set change event on your select box and after create object file from selected filepatch dispatch change file and do it like

```js
  const jsmediatags = window.jsmediatags;

  document.querySelector("#select").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const fileInput = document.querySelector('#input');

    const selectedFile = new File([e.target.value.split("\\").slice(-1).pop()], e.target.value, {
      type: 'video/*',
      lastModified: new Date(),
    });

    const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
    dataTransfer.items.add(selectedFile);
    fileInput.files = dataTransfer.files;

    if (fileInput.webkitEntries.length) {
      fileInput.dataset.file = `${dataTransfer.files[0].name}`;
    }
    $("#input").trigger("change");
  })
  document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    const file = $('#input').files[0];
    jsmediatags.read(file, {
      onSuccess: function (tag) {

        // Array buffer to base64
        const data = tag.tags.picture.data;
        const format = tag.tags.picture.format;
        let base64String = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          base64String += String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        }

        // Output media tags
        document.querySelector("#cover").style.backgroundImage = `url(data:${format};base64,${window.btoa(base64String)})`;

        document.querySelector("#title").textContent = tag.tags.title;
        document.querySelector("#artist").textContent = tag.tags.artist;
        document.querySelector("#album").textContent = tag.tags.album;
        document.querySelector("#genre").textContent = tag.tags.genre;
      },
      onError: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
  
    $(document).on("change", ".file_multi_video", function (evt) {
    var $source = $('#video_here');
    $source[0].src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
    $source.parent()[0].load();
  });
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="one">
    <select id="select" name="file[]"  >
      <option value="#">Movies list</option>
      <option value="media/video/1stvideo.mp4">first</option>
      <option value="media/video/2ndvideo.mp4">second</option>
      <option value="media/video/3rdvideo.mp4">third</option>
    </select>
    <input style="display: none;" type="file" id="input" name="file[]" class="file_multi_video hidden" accept="video/*">
    <div id="cover"></div>
    <p id="title"></p>
    <p id="artist"></p>
    <p id="album"></p>
    <p id="genre"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <video controls>
      <source src="" id="video_here" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsmediatags/3.9.5/jsmediatags.min.js"></script>
```